How to send emails with exim4 through 3 smarthosts and about 10 mail addresses
I am totally stuck...
I am trying to set up an exim4 server to send out mails through smarthosts only.
This is how it looks like:
My email addresses:

1@gmx.net
2@gmx.net
3@gmx.net
4@hotmail.com
5@OTHERDOMAIN.com

Contents of a few of the exim4 config files:
-> /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf:
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='lnxmailsrv; lnxmailsrv.lone; lone'
dc_local_interfaces='192.168.111.200; 127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost='OTHERDOMAIN.com'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_relay_domains='*'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='mail.gmx.net::587;smtp-mail.outlook.com::587;mail.OTHERDOMAIN.com::587;'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'

-> /etc/mailname:
OTHERDOMAIN.com

-> /etc/exim4/passwd.client (some server-specs are noted as regexp, but that does not seem to make any difference):
^mail\.gmx\.net:1@gmx.net:PASSWORD1
^mail\.gmx\.net:2@gmx.net:PASSWORD2
^mail\.gmx\.net:3@gmx.net:PASSWORD3
smtp-mail.outlook.com:4@hotmail.com:PASSWORD4
mail.OTHERDOMAIN.com:5@OTHERDOMAIN.com:PASSWORD5

I have already tried with "transport" und "router" entries within the respective files under
  /etc/exim4/conf.d/
but without any success.
I can send mails from one single address only: 1@gmx.net
All other throw error messages of the kind you can see below in excerpts of  /var/log/exim4/mainlog:
In the first example below I tried to send a mail from "5@OTHERDOMAIN.com" to "3@gmx.net":
2024-05-01 20:59:18 1s2FAk-005IAz-0z <= 5@OTHERDOMAIN.com H=([192.168.111.233]) [192.168.111.233] P=esmtp S=581 id=ba0afe2e-b000-4afe-b376-43e7b4704a3d@OTHERDOMAIN.com
2024-05-01 20:59:18 1s2FAk-005IAz-0z ** 3@gmx.net R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost H=mail.gmx.net [212.227.17.168] X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=yes DN="C=DE,ST=Rheinland-Pfalz,L=Montabaur,O=1&1 Mail & Media GmbH,CN=mail.gmx.net": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<5@OTHERDOMAIN.com> SIZE=1639: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable\n550 Sender address is not allowed.

You can see that exim uses the wrong smarthost, but this can not be the only fault, as....
....in the following example I tried to send a mail from "2@gmx.net" to "3@gmx.net", so the SMTP server would be correct, but still it is not working:
2024-05-02 18:11:05 1s2Z1V-005SwZ-0r <= 2@gmx.net H=([192.168.111.233]) [192.168.111.233] P=esmtps X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_X25519__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_128_GCM:128 CV=no S=615 id=e42ac321-e1fc-4268-a81c-0f2ca6c86a69@gmx.net
2024-05-02 18:11:05 1s2Z1V-005SwZ-0r **3@gmx.net R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost H=mail.gmx.net [212.227.17.168] X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=yes DN="C=DE,ST=Rheinland-Pfalz,L=Montabaur,O=1&1 Mail & Media GmbH,CN=mail.gmx.net": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<2@gmx.net> SIZE=1666: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable\n550 Sender address is not allowed.

Thanks for all the help!
Schogol
BTW: Receiving mails which are fetched by Getmail for Dovecot IMAP server functions wonderfully.
